# how to fix this error "another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'name' was called on null"? (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to call the name and the price and image url from Items_list.dart,
here is the code for calling them:

```
// to get items from Itims_list.dart

 final items item;
  _FruitsState({@required this.item});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0.0),
  child: GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems.length,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: height / width / 3,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return single_fruit(
          prodName: item.name, // error shows in this line
          prodPrice: item.price, // error shows in this line
          prodPicture: item.picture, // error shows in this line
        );
      }),
);
```

And this is the Items_list.dart:

```
 FruitsItemsList fruitsItemsList = FruitsItemsList(fruitsItems: [
      items(
        id: 001,
        name: "kiwi",
        picture: "assets/kiwi1.jpg",
        price: 7,
      ),
      items(
        id: 002,
        name: "avocado",
        picture: "assets/a1.jpg",
        price: 11,
      ),
    
    ]);
    
    class FruitsItemsList {
      List<items> fruitsItems;
      FruitsItemsList({@required this.fruitsItems});
    }
    
    class items {
      int id;
      String name;
      double price;
      String picture;
      int quantity;
    
      items({
        @required this.id,
        @required this.name,
        @required this.price,
        @required this.picture,
        this.quantity = 1,
      });
    
    }
```

Error that I got:
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The getter 'name' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: name // and for the price and picture to not only name.

Comment: Where are you using the index of your itembuilder to select the item?

Comment: I do not use it, any suggestions?

Comment: Use it!  How will your itemBuilder know which item to build? something like `fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems[item]` will be a specific item, on which you can call .name and .price, etc.

Comment: fine, and how it will be useed here ?                                                                  
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return single_fruit(
          prodName: item.name, // error shows in this line
          prodPrice: item.price, // error shows in this line
          prodPicture: item.picture, // error shows in this line
        );

Comment: Note the [item] in my expression.  That is a list method that picks one of the items out of all of the items in the list.  That can then have .name and .price called on it.

Comment: sorry for making it too long :(, but I tried this (prodName: fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems[item].name,) and it did not work.

Comment: Also, not sure why the `items` class is not singular.  It's just one item, right?

Comment: shows underline on [item]The argument type 'items' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Comment: And you called .price on that, or .name?

Comment: At this point, your question is becoming more and more specialized, and it's becoming obvious that you need some basic training in dart.  Please read through the dart.dev language tour and library.tour, and try some of the codelabs there.

Comment: .name Sir, but it will shows the problem for all of them(.name, .price, .picture)

Comment: Ooof sorry.  You want [index] there, not [item].  That's what you get for misnaming your class as "items".

Comment: Hello again Sir, I have a quick question when I do `snapshot.data.fruitsItemsList.fruitsItems.length` I get this error : The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<List<items>>(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<items>, AsyncSnapshot<List<items>>>#dac08):
Class 'List<items>' has no instance getter 'fruitsItemsList'.
Receiver: Instance(length:0) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: fruitsItemsList, Can you help me please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226498/discussion-between-randal-schwartz-and-noor-eddin-hasan).